# get visitor's lat & long and display google map of it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get visitor's location and then display their location using a map.

I tried passing lat and long values to variables a and b and then using that to display a map.

```
  <p> You are visiting me from:

  <button onclick="getLocation()">Click Here</button>
  </p>
  <p id="geoLoc"></p>

  <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("geoLoc");
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
       a = position.coords.latitude;
        b = position.coords.longitude;
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + a +
        "<br>Longitude: " + b;

    }
    function initMap() {
  // The location of visitor
  var uluru = {lat: a, lng: b};
  // The map, centered at visitor
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
  // The marker, positioned at visitor
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
  </script>
  <h3> Map of Your Location</h3>
  <div id = "map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </div>
```

expected: see the map with marker on the location passed by latitude and longitude

actual: nothing

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a height to the div that contains the map for it to display, adding `style="height: 500px"` to the attributes did the trick.

The map is also being initialised when you load the page, which will display a marker at (0,0). The position of the marker will need to be set after you have received the geolocation information from the visitor. The map and marker variables need to be defined outside of the function scope and then you can set the marker in your `showPosition` function.

```
<p> You are visiting me from:
<button onclick="getLocation()">Click Here</button>
</p>
<p id="geoLoc"></p>

<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("geoLoc");
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  // Map variables with global scope
  var map;
  var marker;

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    a = position.coords.latitude;
    b = position.coords.longitude;
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + a +
    "<br>Longitude: " + b;
    // Position of the visitor
    var uluru = {lat: a, lng: b};
    // The marker, positioned at visitor
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
    // Center the map on the new marker position
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  }

  function initMap() {
    // The map, centered to 0,0
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4 , center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}});
  }

</script>
<h3> Map of Your Location</h3>
<!-- Set div height for the map -->
<div id = "map" style="height: 500px;"></div>
  <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general answer would be [GeoLocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) and [Display Map](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp). Mix as you go along - w3schools is a sure place for beginners.